# Get rows as result instead of columns

Tags: mysql

I have following tables:

> treatments: id, name, base_price, companies_id
>
> companies: id, name
>
> prices: id, treatment_id, companies_id, comp_price

I want to create a select to display the treatment names with the respective company prices as follows:

> t.name | t.base_price | p.comp_price (for company #1) | p.comp_price (for company #2) | p.comp_price (for company #3) | p.comp_price (for company #4) | etc...

The number of companies is variable.

With following SELECT:

```
`SELECT t.name, c.name, p.comp_price from treatments t left join prices p on p.treatment_id = t.id`
```

I get a row for each comp_price and I need a row for each treatment...

Comment: Sorry , didnt get it,Please explain Properly .And write what result you expect by editing questoin also tell what result you are getting now ?

Comment: You are looking for what is called a crosstab or pivot query

Comment: The common way to do it would be to select 1 row per company & treatment and iterate over them on the application layer.

Comment: Oh, and: MySQL doesn't implement any pivot keyword/function. So there is no easy way.

Comment: This is not clear. But if it were clear it would be a faq. Before considering posting please always google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tony Hopkinson took me to the right way! I used GROUP_CONCAT() and GROUP BY in the MYSQL query and it works!

```
SELECT t.name, c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(p.comp_price) FROM treatments t LEFT JOIN prices p ON p.treatment_id = t.id` GROUP BY t.name
```

Thanks all for the hints!